# Determine memory layout (ColMajor/RowMajor) in tensorflow custom op.

Tags: tensorflow, eigen

I've wrote a custom tensorflow op that reshapes Eigen::Tensors and I need to determine if the inputs are row or column major aligned.

I tried casting to EigenMatrixBase, but it didn't work.

Comment: tensors should be all row-major order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen Tensors support both Column and Row Major layouts. However, TensorFlow operations always use the Row Major layout, so you can expect the input and output tensors to be Row Major.